# How to hide entire table row if v-for is nested in a table cell?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a table where VueJS renders a list like so, but how do I hide the table row section named `Regional` if there is no data for the property `ConstRegional` or `ConstRegional-P` or `ConstRegional-S`?

```
<table class='table'>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th style='border-top: none'>Regional:</th>
                  <td style='border-top: none'>
                    <ul>
                      <template v-for='item in ec'>
                      <li v-if='item["Extraction Criteria"] == "ConstRegional"' :key='item["Extraction Criteria"]'>
                        {{item['Collection Requirements']}}
                      </li>
                      <li v-if='item["Extraction Criteria"] == "ConstRegional-P"' :key='item["Extraction Criteria"]'>
                        {{item['Collection Requirements']}}
                      </li>
                      <li v-if='item["Extraction Criteria"] == "ConstRegional-S"' :key='item["Extraction Criteria"]'>
                        {{item['Collection Requirements']}}
                      </li>
                      </template>
                    </ul>
                  </td>
              </tr>
....snip
```

Comment: combine all conditions with "or" like `v-if="item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional-P' || item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional-S' || item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional'"`

Comment: Generally, `th` elements are nested inside the `thead` element. You also indent the `th` element which immediately follows the `th` element, did you mean to nest this inside the `th` element? You have an interesting table layout for sure. You might benefit from the guides here https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/.

Comment: Do you want to hide the row if the data properties you mentioned don't exists for *every* element in `ec`, or *any* element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<tr>` tag you can add a filter check on length like below, to hide the entire `<tr>` when all of the required properties are not found.

```
<tr v-if="ec.filter((item) => item['Extraction Criteria'] == 'ConstRegional-P' || item['Extraction Criteria'] == 'ConstRegional-S' || item['Extraction Criteria'] == 'ConstRegional').length"</tr>
```

So no need of writing 3 `v-if` inside your `v-for`,
this will be enough `{{item['Collection Requirements']}}`

To make it cleaner you can take the filter inside `methods`.

```js
function callMe() {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
      filterLen:false,
      ec: [/*{
          "Extraction Criteria":"ConstRegional-P"
        },
        {
          "Extraction Criteria":"ConstRegional-S"
        },
        {
          "Extraction Criteria":"ConstRegional"
        },*/
        {
          "Extraction Criteria":"Test"
        }
      ]
    },
    created(){
     this.isAllPresent()
    },
    methods: {
     isAllPresent:function(){
        
        this.filterLen= this.ec.filter((item) => {
        return item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional-P' || item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional-S' || item["Extraction Criteria"] == 'ConstRegional'
        }).length
     
     }

    }

  })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr v-if="filterLen">
    <th style='border-top: none'>Regional:</th>
    <td style='border-top: none'>
      <ul>
        <template v-for='item in ec'>
          <li>{{item["Extraction Criteria"]}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-else>
  Nothing present
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```